# How can I convert an array of integers into an array of digits for further processing?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer

I want to break given numbers into digits and sort. I expect to get:

```
unused_digits(2015, 8, 26) # => [0,1,2,2,5,6,8]
```

I tried:

```
def unused_digits(*x)
  x # => [2015, 8, 26]
  x = x.join.split "" # => [2, 0, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6]
  x = x.to_a # => [2, 0, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6]
  # other stuff here
  return x
end
```

---

if you are confused about the name "unused_digits". please ignore the name "unused_digits", and just treat it as "find_out_used_digits".

Originally I was going to find out the unused digits, but I was stuck at first stage finding used digits, so I just copied the first code for finding digits, and didn't copy the rest code to find unused ones. my bad. apologies.

Comment: What is the expected output for `unused_digits(2015,8,26)`?

Comment: `*x` means, that whatever (number of) args you pass - `x` would be an array

Comment: I want to break each number and sort after. so the output will be [0,1,2,2,5,6,8] @WandMaker

Comment: Note for future visitors: this question has been heavily edited by several people for readability and clarity. Please keep that in mind as you review the answers.

Comment: There's been editing of the question, and there's a difference of opinion what the desired results were, based upon looking at the answers. It appears the question wasn't asked clearly, and remains unclear. Perhaps, instead of trying to create answers, it would have been better to close the question until it could be asked clearly and in a way that didn't generate multiple choices? Remember, SO isn't a race for points, it's an attempt to build usable programming solutions for clearly defined problems, i.e., a reference book.

Comment: Why is the method called `unused_digits` when it returns the digits that were _used_?

Comment: @theTinMan, sorry for the unclear question, my bad. I am not trying to get points. I don't need to do that. I am just trying to learn Ruby and ask for help. I have added some more comments on my original question. thanks and sorry about that.

Comment: @WayneConrad, please ignore, originally I was going to find out the unused digits, but I was stuck at first stage finding used digits, so I just copied the first code, and didn't copy the rest code to find unused ones. my bad. apologies.

Answer (score 3):

For the problem described in comments, here is the solution:

```
def unused_digits(*x)
    x.join.chars.sort.map(&:to_i)
end

unused_digits(2015,8,26)
#=> [0, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 8]
```

1. `x` is an array of arguments - `[2015, 8, 26]`
2. `.join` will join the arguments into a string and give us `"2015826"`
3. `.chars` will split the string into chars.
4. `.sort` will sort that character array
5. `.map(&:to_i)` will take each char and convert to number

Comment: Think you can miss out step 2 and get the same output?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Yeah!  Thanks, will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Your question appears to be an X/Y problem, in large part because the name of your method (e.g. "unused_digits") doesn't actually seem to have anything to do with your expected return values. As originally posted, your method returns an array of *used* digits rather than *unused* digits.

If you truly want the return value to be `[0,1,2,2,5,6,8]` [per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751815/cannot-convert-string-into-array-in-ruby#comment57251083_34751815), then others have already posted useful answers. However, in the event that you actually want to return the digits that have *not* been used in any of your arguments (as suggested by your method name), then you may want to try the alternative described below.

### Find Unused Digits with Array Difference

You can use various [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) functions to flatten an array of integers, and then use the [Array difference](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2D) method to return a de-duplicated list of unused digits. For example:

```
def unused_digits *integer_array
  Array(0..9) - integer_array.flatten.join.scan(/\d/).sort.map(&:to_i)
end

unused_digits 2015, 8, 26
#=> [3, 4, 7, 9]

unused_digits 2345678
#=> [0, 1, 9]
```

This will correctly return an array of digits that are *not* included in any passed arguments. This seems to be what is intended by your method name, but your mileage may certainly vary.

Comment: thanks for helping me edit the original post. my bad. apologies.  originally I was going to find out the unused digits, but I was stuck at first stage finding used digits, so I just copied the first code, and didn't copy the rest code to find unused ones.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning your function, you already have an array: `[2015, 8, 26]`. If that's what you want, then you don't have to do anything else.

By then calling `split("")` directly after `join`, you are converting your initial array into a string, then back into an array.

By way of an example, this is executing what is essentially the same code in `irb`, the interactive ruby shell:

```
>> digits = 2015,8,26
=> [2015, 8, 26]
>> joined = digits.join
=> "2015826"
>> split = joined.split("")
=> ["2", "0", "1", "5", "8", "2", "6"]
>> split.to_a
=> ["2", "0", "1", "5", "8", "2", "6"]
>> split.class
=> Array
```

As you can see, when you call `join`, your `2015,8,26` turns into `"2015826"`, which is a string. After you call `split""`, it becomes an array with *each* character as a separate element in the array.

Calling `to_a` on what is already an array has no effect.

Hopefully that's helpful!

Comment: you are correct! thanks ! I didn't know when passing multipy arguments then it will auto be an array. I tried to sort out the array after....

Answer (score 0):

```
def unused_digits(*x)
x.flat_map { |n| n.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i) }.sort
end

unused_digits(2015,8,26)
  #=> [0,1,2,2,5,6,8]
```